# Why is this model not a Markov chain?

Tags: markov-chains

I'm new to probability models.

Taken from Ross' Introduction to Probability Models 11th ed:

"Example 4.4 (Transforming a Process into a Markov Chain)

Suppose that whether
or not it rains today depends on previous weather conditions through the last two days.
Specifically, suppose that if it has rained for the past two days, then it will rain tomorrow with probability 0.7; if it rained today but not yesterday, then it will rain tomorrow
with probability 0.5; if it rained yesterday but not today, then it will rain tomorrow with
probability 0.4; if it has not rained in the past two days, then it will rain tomorrow with
probability 0.2.
If we let the state at time n depend only on whether or not it is raining at time n, then
the preceding model is not a Markov chain (why not?)."

I know that a Markov chain as defined in the book must satisfy the Markovian property, i.e. given the present, the future is independent of the past, and that there is a fixed prob. of going from state i to state j, but I can't seem to connect this to the example. Any help?

Comment: It says "If we let the state at time $n$ depend ONLY on whether or not it is raining at time $n$ ...''. Given this state, the probability of rain at time $n+1$ is not independent of the past, because it depends also on whether it has rained at time $n-1$.

Comment: What is the _exact_ wording of the Markovian property in your book? Because this question is possibly about nitpicking on a word-by-word level, and we can't help you do that without knowing which words to nitpick about.

Comment: @Arthur Let $\{X_n, n = 0,1,2,\dots\}$ be a stochastic process that takes on a finite or countable number of possible values. If $X_n = i$, then the process is said to be in state $i$ at time $n$. We suppose that whenever the process is in state $i$, there is a fixed probability $P_{ij}$ that it will next be in state $j$. That is, we suppose that $P\{X_{n+1} = j | X_n = i, X_{n-1} = i_{n-i}, \dots, X_1 = i_1, X_0 = i_0\} = P_{ij}$ for all states $i_0,i_1,\dots,i_{n-1},i,j$ and all $n \geq 0$. Such a stochastic process is known as a Markov chain.

Answer (score 1):

My (possible) interpretation is that,
while it is perfectly possible to express the chain
by a $4 \times 4$ matrix relating $4$-D vectors
representing the status of two consecutive days
$(rain \& rain, rain \& not-rain, \cdots)$,
you cannot represent it by  $2$-D vectors
relevant only to the state of a single day.